# $ I_n =\int_0 ^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^nx \cos nx dx$ Express $I_n$ in terms of $I_{n-1}$ Can I use complex numbers in it ??

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> Let$$ I_n =\int_0 ^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^nx\cos nx\, dx$$
>    Express $I_n$ in terms of $I_{n-1}$

I had a thought about the possibility of using complex numbers in this. I'm in highschool and this is something obviously not taught and neither do I know the proper theory , and one of my friends told me about this possibility.

What I thought was to write it as $Re\{\int_0 ^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^nx e^{inx}dx\}$ but after this I could not think of any way that could help. Is it really a dead end ?? Is this even correct?? Could something be done after this ?? Is this a way/method of evaluation of integrals ?? (Just like eg substitution) If yes , is there a place where I could look up the proper theory for it.

Even though the solution itself is as easy as applying by parts and manipulation, but I just want to know if my initial thought could also have lead to the same result.

Comment: $\cos^n x$ is not the real part of $e^{inx}$. Try a couple of integrations by parts instead.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet sorry , I made a mistake while writing, I missed the ^ and while proof reading it, did my really pay a lot of attention. Sorry...

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I know how to get the solution. I'm just looking for the possibility with this thought